# How can I make a title carry over to the next page if it is left alone (without text following it)?

Tags: epub

In the Pages program, there is an option to link paragraphs or any blocks of text to each other.
This is needed, for example, so that a title is carried to the next page with the main  text, rather than remaining on the previous page alone.
But when converted to epub format, this binding disappears.
Is this a specific feature of the epub format itself or can this link between text blocks be implemented in some other program?
If yes, how can it be realized?

Comment: Is your question about linked text boxes called a 'thread' ... or is it a question about H1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 + first paragraph being linked together using a CSS break-inside:avoid method? Welcome to ESE.   https://support.apple.com/guide/pages/link-text-boxes-tan6d9592dde/mac

Comment: The information about thread blocks is very interesting, thanks! I'll familiarize myself with it if possible. But. i am wondering why my formatting is lost when converting to epub-format. I want my header in the epub file (H1, H2, etc) to go to the next page if it is left alone.